# Add new lines to top and bottom of every text file

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a folder that contains about 2000 text files in it.

At the top of every file I need these two lines added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

And at the bottom of each file I need this added:

```
</urlset>
```

Is there any way to massively do this across all the files at once via command line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat header 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

$ cat footer 
</urlset>

$ cat header file footer
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
one line
</urlset>
```

To wrap the above in a bash-loop:

```
for f in *.xml; do cat header $f footer > tmp && mv tmp $f; done
```

Comment: `cat file1 | cat - file2 | cat - file3`? Really? How about `cat file1 file2 file3`...?

Comment: @twalberg - I blame sleep deprivation. Stupid!

Answer (score 1):

With a one-liner :

```
sed -i -e '1 i <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' -e '$s@$@\n</urlset>@'  *.xml
```