# add line at top and bottom of file before sending it to pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file, say, `text`.

What I want to do is to put the text file into pipe (as in `cat text |`), but with added line at top and bottom - but without creating a new file (because the `text` file is kind of big) or modifying it.

Is that possible? I was thinking `echo $(echo "line"; cat text; echo "line")` but I don't like that.

Comment: In bash the parenthesis alone (without the first echo and the `$`) should work.

Comment: You can also just create a file for the extra line and do: `cat first-line text`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From man bash:

> (list) list  is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).  Variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.
>                The return status is the exit status of list.

So this should work:

```
(echo first line; cat file; echo last line) | some_command
```

As suggested by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), when you don't need a subshell you can use `{}` instead of `()`. In this case, the `;` is mandatory including for the last command in the group.

In the comments Pyrolistical remembers this also works if you have an incoming pipe instead of a file:

```
some_program | (echo first line; cat -; echo last line) | some-other-command
```

As in many unix command line applications, if the filename argument for `cat` is `-` it means "read from standard input".

Comment: You can also use a simple command group here: `{ echo first; cat file; echo last; } | some_command`. There's no need for a subshell

Comment: I thought there might be something simpler than convoluted sed. Thanks!

Comment: @chepner: when I do that, the file seems to print on STDOUT instead of to the pipe.

Comment: And if you have an incoming pipe you can `some-program | (echo first line; cat -; echo last line) | some-other-command`

Comment: @Pyrolistical you should add that as a separate answer for more visibility. That's what I wanted but I missed it the first time I read this page.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from this question [Add new lines to top and bottom of every text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967842/add-new-lines-to-top-and-bottom-of-every-text-file):

```
cat text |sed -e '1 i beginning_line'| sed -e '$s@$@\nending_line@' |
```

it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

add lines to the pipe output,
add a line to the top: (source - @Karel Bilek's comment)

```
cat text.txt | sed -e '1 i my first line'
```

add a line to the bottom: ( source - https://askubuntu.com/a/968585 )

```
cat text.txt | sed -e '$a my last line'
```

e.g: try this with single quotes

```
cat text.txt | sed -e '1 i my first line' | sed -e '$a my last line'
```

output:

```
my first line
this is
my
text
file
my last line
```